# To what pressure should I pump my 2.4 inch punctured tubeless tyre?

Tags: puncture, tubeless

[The tale of a tire]
I had a puncture in my tyre. I refilled the sealing liquid, inflated it to 3 atmospheres and rode approx 9 km (including stairs and small jumps) to work. Checked the pressue and it seemed to be quite the same as before the ride. I parked the bike in my office and then after 2 hours all of a sudden heard hissing - apparently the hole reopened. I turned the wheel so that the sealant might be just above the hole and the hole closed again. On my way to work I inflated it again to 3 atmospheres but then yet again the hole reopened - but then after a moment sealed itself again. I did not increase the pressue again and it seems to be maybe around 1.5 atmospheres.

What can I do to be able to ride 2.8 -3 atmospheres again (as I am rather on the heavier side...)? Should I pump the tyre to 4 atmospheres, let the hole open and close again and then I can ride with 3 a?

Comment: Sounds like you are running at very high pressures.  I would assume most people aren't running more than 2 atmospheres for a wider tire like that, especially tubeless.  (For our non-metric members, 2 Atmospheres/Bar = 29.4psi and 3 atmospheres = 44psi.)

Comment: hmmm.. might be 100kg or slightly more with all the gear...

Comment: I am also around 100kg and am running on 2.25" tires.  I do a mix of trail riding and city riding and don't usually take the time to adjust my pressures.  Even if I know I am only riding on the road, I never go beyond 35psi (2.3 bar).

Comment: cheers. so now how do you proceed when you have a puncture? pump it to higher pressure first? or to 2.3 bar and just ignore what happens afterwards?

Comment: I run quite a bit of sealant in my tires and have never had an issue.  Most times I get punctures I don't even realize it happened.  Only once have I had a puncture that didn't seal within one rotation of the wheel.  So yeah, I would pump to 2.3 bar and just ride it.  It it doesn't seal, then use the plugs, or patch the tire from the inside, or if you are in a pinch on the trail, throw a regular tube in there to get you home.

Comment: You may need to patch from the inside.
'Normal' pressure range for a 2.4 tubeless tyre would be 18-30psi

Comment: @BenKickert when you use inner tubes for repairs do you get the valves out without tools?

Comment: To be honest with you, I don't even carry a spare tube with me any more.  I have found a hole big enough to cause issues with tubeless tires is probably going to cause issues even with a tube (like a sidewall tear).  I do usually carry a CO2 pump just in case, but for where and when I ride, I can just call my wife for help if I ever have a catostrophic blow out.  But to answer your question, it is usually very easy to remove the stem to put a tube in: [youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_StqLLpAVI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a first pass leave the tire at the lower pressure for a day or so to let the sealant plug harden. Then try and inflate to a higher pressure and see if it holds. Sometimes you need some curing time.

If that fails, try using the tubeless plugs as suggested in the answer by Girgory Rechistov.

Answer (score 2):

There are special plugs (and tools used to install them) sold that are used together with the sealant to plug bigger kinds of punctures. Maybe it will help in your case.

[image: Example Bacon Strips]

Comment: thank you Grigory. the hole isn't that big tho.. in fact I'm after the optimal procedure of inflating and pressure and stuff.

Comment: I'm surprised that a company would be claiming to be "#1 in CO2" in these environmentally conscious times. ;-)